# rails,authlogic and sql error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm trying to build an authentication system with an admin_name and password in rails using authlogic.  I'm getting the following error:

> Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') = '[admin_name]') LIMIT 1' at line 1: SELECT `admins`.* FROM `admins` WHERE (LOWER(`admins`.) = '[admin_name]') LIMIT 1

This is the code in admin_session_controller.rb...

```
def login
  @admin_session = AdminSession.new(params[:admin_session])                   
if @admin_session.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Successfuly logged in.'
  redirect_to :controller => 'admins', :action => 'email_stats'
else
  flash[:notice] = 'Trouble!!'
  render :action => 'new'
end
end
```

I'm guessing that it doesn't like `params[:admin_session]`, but I don't really know why.

the erb template....

```
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/head_admins' %>

<div id="notice">
<% if flash[:notice] %>
<%= flash[:notice] %>
<% end %>
</div>

<div id="main" align="middle">
  <table>
    <%= form_for @admin_session, :as => :admin_session, :url => { :action => "login" } do |f| %>
    <tr class="bold gray">Admin_name</tr>
    <tr id="login_admin_name"><%= f.text_field :admin_name, :class => "text", :tabindex => "1" %></tr>
    <tr class="bold gray">Password</tr>
    <tr id="login_password"><%= f.password_field :password, :class => "password", :tabindex => "2" %></tr>
    <tr><%= image_submit_tag("login_btn.png", :id => 'login_btn', :class=>"image", :tabindex => "3", :alt => 'Login') %></tr>
    <tr class="gray"><%= f.check_box :remember_me %>Keep me logged in</tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the error log:

```
    Started POST "/admin_session/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-17 19:58:07 -0700
  Processing by AdminSessionController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[token]", "admin_session"=>{"admin_name"=>"[admin_name]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "x"=>"35", "y"=>"14"}
  [1m[36mAdmin Load (136.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `admins`.* FROM `admins` WHERE (LOWER(`admins`.) = '[admin_name]') LIMIT 1[0m
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') = '[admin_name]') LIMIT 1' at line 1: SELECT `admins`.* FROM `admins` WHERE (LOWER(`admins`.) = '[admin_name]') LIMIT 1
Completed   in 563ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') = '[admin_name]') LIMIT 1' at line 1: SELECT `admins`.* FROM `admins` WHERE (LOWER(`admins`.) = '[admin_name]') LIMIT 1):
  app/controllers/admin_session_controller.rb:18:in `login'

Rendered /home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.8ms)
Rendered /home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (6.7m
```

this is the full trace......

```
 activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:202:in `rescue in log'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:194:in `log'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:289:in `execute'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:619:in `select'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:54:in `block in select_all'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:68:in `cache_sql'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:54:in `select_all'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:467:in `find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `to_a'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:333:in `find_first'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:122:in `first'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:119:in `first'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:439:in `first'
/home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/login.rb:121:in `find_with_case'
/home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/login.rb:112:in `find_by_smart_case_login_field'
/home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:95:in `block in search_for_record'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:1121:in `with_scope'
/home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/session/scopes.rb:94:in `search_for_record'
/home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/session/password.rb:183:in `validate_by_password'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
/home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:87:in `validate'
/home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/session/validation.rb:64:in `valid?'
/home/tm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/authlogic-a087ad0cba3c/lib/authlogic/session/existence.rb:65:in `save'
app/controllers/admin_session_controller.rb:19:in `login'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `_run__640502527__process_action__573632350__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:295:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:353:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:67:in `process'
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2) lib/mongrel.rb:165:in `block in process_client'
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2) lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `each'
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2) lib/mongrel.rb:164:in `process_client'
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2) lib/mongrel.rb:291:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

thanks...

Comment: The error is for the SQL statement, nothing to do with ruby...

Comment: what's is your login erb template? can you provide **logger.error params[:admin_session]** please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you didn't really type "[admin_name]" into the text field, but tweaked the logs you're showing us?

Are you telling Authlogic what field to use for the login field?  Unless it's one of the defaults then that might explain why the SQL generated doesn't contain an actual column name to compare against...

```
SELECT `admins`.* FROM `admins` WHERE (LOWER(`admins`.) = '[admin_name]')
```